# how to use the Pentaho data integration for reporting

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, saiku

In my project we are using `Pentaho data integration` , `saiku-server` for reporting.

Now i am new to the business intelligence thing and i am confused which functioning will be performed by which software.

Senior coder here dont tell me so thats why i am asking here.

I am confused what are the functioning provided by these tools

`Pentahoo`

`PAN`

`Kitchen`

`Spoon`

`Saiku`

There are scripting which generates the these four files

`cube.json` `sims.json` `schema.json` `path.json`

now i don't know which software will be using that json files pentahoo , saiku spoon or what.

can anyone give me some idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho data integration is one of open source tool provided by pentaho suit.

Spoon is used to create transformation using GUI interface.

if you simply want to run the transformations and jobs then use kitchen or spoon. (mainly used for running this things using command line)

saiku is a 1 of server, pentaho itself has a server (pentaho bi server) and in this you can add saiku pluggin for displaying cubes which are designed in pentaho schema workbench.

for more understanding google the terms which i mansion in the answer.

Comment: yes you can..
Create cube according to requirement and publish it in bi server. and add saiku pluggin in BI server.

Comment: i have never done it before so can't tell you, bit for data integration eclipse plugin is available.